# Azure Blueprint deny read access to some admins

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-rbac, azure-blueprints

I need to allow only a couple of administrators access to a ressource group, I tried blueprints using the UI but I am only able to lock delete.

1. Is it possible to block reading a ressource or ressource group?
2. do I need to use REST API for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to block reading a resource or ressource group?

No, we cannot block the access to read a particular resource or a resource group.

Currently these are all the list of supported resource group locks as mentioned here in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/concepts/resource-locking#locking-modes-and-states).

*Below is the state of a resource:*
[image]